# Stack error when calling asm routine from C code

Tags: gcc, x86, kernel, nasm, osdev

I am using a cross compiler (target elf-i686), and using the following codes:

```
[bits 32]
global _printcool
global _wait

_printcool:
mov byte [0xB8000], 'R'
mov byte [0xB8001], 0x52
add esp, 4 ; <-- Tried to remove it, nothing changes
ret ; <-- If replaced by jmp $, no triple fault

_wait:
jmp _wait
```

And the C code:

```
kmain();

extern void _printcool();
extern void _wait();

int kmain()
{
 _printcool();
 while(1==1){}
 return 0;
}
```

For compilation, I use:

```
nasm -f elf kernelasm.asm -o kernelasm.o
i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -fno-pic -fno-pie -c kernelc.c -o kernelc.o
i686-elf-ld --oformat binary -Ttext 0x1000 kernelasm.o kernelc.o -o kernel.bin
```

Then I run It using qemu, like I always did. The problem comes from the ret instruction when **_printcool** is called, a character is printed but It instantly reboots the machine after. If I replace the ret instruction by **jmp $**, no problems.

I think the problem may come from the fact that I don't clean the stack, but even after a lot of tries, I cannot get this code to run properly.

Comment: The `add esp, 4` certainly shouldn't be there, it makes no sense and will obviously cause a return to the wrong place.

Comment: You haven't said how you are running qemu to boot this code (how do you get into protected mode?) but it looks to me like control will start at the beginning of the code, which is `_printcool` itself.  I don't see how `_kmain` can be called, and so I don't think you are getting to `_printcool` via the call from `_kmain`.  Therefore there is no return address on the stack, so `ret` can't return anywhere meaningful.  (Indeed it's not clear whether the stack pointer actually points to any usable memory at all.)

Comment: The `kmain();` at the top of your C file looks like an attempt to have `kmain()` called from "top level" but C has no such thing.  That line is parsed as a declaration of the function `kmain` with implicit return type `int` and unspecified arguments, and has no effect on the generated code.  If you want to get `kmain` called you have to write assembly code that calls it, first setting up the stack and everything else in the way the ABI expects it to be.

Comment: After calling my main kernel function from assembly, it indeed works. I am still confused about how could I tell ld where is my entry point (the asm file or c file). But it is now working and I will look forward into it. Thank you !

Comment: With an ordinary executable, when you tell ld your entry point, it sets that address as a field in the executable's header, and the OS starts execution there.  For a boot sector, there's no such header, and execution always begins at the beginning.  I think by default ld will link so that the `.text` section comes first, and its contents come from the `.text` sections of the object files you linked, in the order that you passed them.  So since you specified `kernelasm.o` first on the command line, it's the code from that file that gets executed.

Comment: You could use a linker script to rearrange this if necessary.  But it probably won't work to try to put a C function at the beginning; there will need to be some assembly code to set up the machine state the way that C compilers expect it to be (like stack).

Comment: Thank you really much for your time. But if I already setup stack segments etc previously in asm just before the jump to this c code (only c code at say 0x1000), it would still be buggy?

Comment: You could create a separate file (like `kernel_bootstrap.asm`) with a `bits 32` directive and a  `extern _kmain` `section .text` `call _kmain` . assemble with nasm and produce a `.o` object file. When linking, list that bootstrap object first. That way the `call _kmain` will be the first instruction in the generated binary. You can also use a linker script to do something similar.

Comment: Looking at yourr code you could do the same thing by placing a `call _kmain` as the first instruction in `kernelasm.asm` . Then always make sure you list `kernelasm.o` as the first object.